# How would I convert a completion hander function to async when recursion is involved?

Tags: swift, recursion, async-await

Currently I call `myFunction` as such:

```
myFunction() { list in
    // do whatever with list
}
```

I would like to be able to call it like this:

```
let list = await myFunction()
// do whatever with list
```

So from what I understand I need to convert `myFunction` to be async. Currently it looks like:

```
func myFunction(currentList: [String] = [], startIndex: Int = 0, completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {
    var list = currentList
    let maxSize = 10
    let endIndex = start + maxSize - 1
    privateFunction(range: startIndex...endIndex) { items in
        list.append(items)
        if items.count < maxSize {
            completion(list)
        } else {
            myFunction(currentList: list, startIndex: startIndex + maxSize, completion: completion)
        }
    }
}
```

However, `myFunction` calls a private function that I do not have access to so cannot modify. I learned that a way to deal with this is to use `withCheckedContinuation`. So I modify `myFunction` to look like this:

```
func myFunction(currentList: [String] = [], startIndex: Int = 0) async -> [String] {
    var list = currentList
    let maxSize = 10
    let endIndex = start + maxSize - 1
    return await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        privateFunction(range: startIndex...endIndex) { items in
            list.append(items)
            if items.count < maxSize {
                continuation.resume(returning: list)
            } else {
                // ???
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what to put in the commented area above, since when that part of the code is reached, the function is to call itself unless the condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

With async-await, the recursion is no longer necessary.

First, you would make an asynchronous rendition of your private function, e.g.

```swift
func privateFunction(range: ClosedRange<Int>) async -> [String] {
    await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        privateFunction(range: range) { items in
            continuation.resume(returning: items)
        }
    }
}
```

And then, `myFunction` is reduced to a simple loop:

```swift
func myFunction() async -> [String] {
    var results: [String] = []
    var items: [String]
    let maxSize = 10
    var startIndex = 0
    
    repeat {
        let endIndex = startIndex + maxSize - 1
        items = await privateFunction(range: startIndex...endIndex)
        results += items
        startIndex += maxSize
    } while items.count >= maxSize 
    
    return results
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this async implementiation of `myFuntion` :

```
    @available(iOS 15.0,tvOS 15.0, macOS 12.0, *)
public func myFunction(currentList: [String] = [], startIndex: Int = 0) async throws -> [String] {
    return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
         self.myFunction(currentList: currentList, startIndex: startIndex) { result in
            continuation.resume(returning: result)
        }
    }
}
```